# Extension on objective c class reports "use of undeclared type"

Tags: objective-c, swift, fmdb

I'm trying to write an extension for "FMDatabase"... an objective c class.

```
extension FMDatabase {


}
```

I am using FMDatabase without problem in other swift code in this project. However in this swift extension it fails compilation with "use of undeclared type FMDatabase".

Answer (score 5):

There's no problem doing Swift extensions on `FMDatabase`. I've done it without incident. Perhaps you're doing this in a separate target that doesn't have access to `FMDatabase`. Or perhaps you neglected to `#import "FMDB.h"` in your bridging header for this target. Also, if you just added the bridging header, sometimes it won't recognize `FMDatabase` (or whatever) until you compile.

If you're still having this problem, please outline the precise steps we need to reproduce the problem (i.e. please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). But I just created a Swift `extension` for  `FMDatabase` and it works fine.

Comment: I already had done all you suggested... and the strange thing is FMDatabase is working in other swift classes... no idea why it would be any different for an extension. I've already lost enough time on this, no time to make a MCVE. It looks like a swift bug to me. But thanks Rob, good to know that it should work.

Answer (score -1):

As i know Swift is not good work with Cocoapods, there some troubles in installation and initialisation.
For you better read the docs of FMDatabase "How to install" on Swift